# Selected Data in CheckBoxList to Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a `CheckBoxList` like this. (There are customer name)

[image: Checkboxlist]

These are customer name and every customer has a customer number (`Unique` -- `Primary Key`)

Table: `S_TEKLIF`

`MUS_K_ISIM` represent Customer Name

`HESAP_NO` represent Customer Number

I have a `Send Button` and `Gridview`.
When i click the Send Button,

In my `Gridview`, I just want run this `SQL`;

```
SELECT A.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 || '/' || A.TEKLIF_NO2 AS TEKLIF, A.MUS_K_ISIM, 
B.MARKA, C.SASI_NO, C.SASI_DURUM, D.TAS_MAR, RISK_SASI(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2, C.SASI_NO) AS RISK,
MV_SASI(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2, C.SASI_NO, SYSDATE) AS MV
FROM S_TEKLIF A,  S_URUN B, S_URUN_DETAY C, KOC_KTMAR_PR D
WHERE A.TEKLIF_NO1 || A.TEKLIF_NO2 = B.TEKLIF_NO1 || B.TEKLIF_NO2
AND A.TEKLIF_NO1 || A.TEKLIF_NO2 = C.TEKLIF_NO1 || C.TEKLIF_NO2
AND B.SIRA_NO = C.URUN_SIRA_NO
AND B.DISTRIBUTOR = D.DIST_KOD
AND B.MARKA = D.MARKA_KOD
AND B.URUN_KOD = D.TAS_KOD
AND A.HESAP_NO IN (
```

But as you can see bottom of th `SQL`, I just want to show "**Which customers i selected in CheckBoxList**" in my Gridview.

How can i do that?

What should be in my `Send_Click()` function and in my `SQL`?

Best Regards, Soner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making statment in plain english format

in your button click event add the code below

```
protected void mybutton_click()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(ListItem item in CustomerListBox.Items)
    {

         If(item.selected)
         {
             sb.Append(item.SelectedValue+",");
         }
    }

    FillGridview(sb);
}

private void FillGridview(StringBuilder sb)
{
    string s = sb.tostring().remove().lastindexof(",");
    //pass this string as param and set it your where condition.
    // Get the datatble or collection and bind grid.
}

Select your desired columsn to display 
From Your Tables (put joins if required)
Where CustomerNumber IN (@CommaSeparatedAboveString_s);
```

Comment: Which function should i add this code? In my opinion SQL must change which i selected in CheckBoxList. Adding some parameter to "AND A.HESAP_NO IN....." Right?

Answer (score 1):

Itrate for each item in your checkbox list and check if the item is checked, if yes then get the customer id against that item (which you might be placing in value attribute of item). Prepare a comma separated list of those customer ids and passed into the IN clause of your SQL. So it would be something like below.

```
SELECT A.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 || '/' || A.TEKLIF_NO2 AS TEKLIF, A.MUS_K_ISIM, 
B.MARKA, C.SASI_NO, C.SASI_DURUM, D.TAS_MAR, RISK_SASI(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2, C.SASI_NO) AS RISK,
MV_SASI(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2, C.SASI_NO, SYSDATE) AS MV
FROM S_TEKLIF A,  S_URUN B, S_URUN_DETAY C, KOC_KTMAR_PR D
WHERE A.TEKLIF_NO1 || A.TEKLIF_NO2 = B.TEKLIF_NO1 || B.TEKLIF_NO2
AND A.TEKLIF_NO1 || A.TEKLIF_NO2 = C.TEKLIF_NO1 || C.TEKLIF_NO2
AND B.SIRA_NO = C.URUN_SIRA_NO
AND B.DISTRIBUTOR = D.DIST_KOD
AND B.MARKA = D.MARKA_KOD
AND B.URUN_KOD = D.TAS_KOD
AND A.HESAP_NO IN (12,14,13,18,26)
```

Comment: You just change AND A.HESAP_NO IN (12,14,13,18,26). Really? I just want learn how can i do that with code? How can i adding a parameter in my SQL? Should i?

Comment: @Soner: I give you the idea on how you can do that, but if you want me to write the SQL and C# functions will a lot more details then it would not be possible :-))